# data is not bound with ng-repeat in radio input in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">       
  <label ng-repeat="x in list">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="test" value="x" >{{x}} 
  </label>   
  <br>
  Exec type: {{test}}   
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) { 
$scope.list = ["xxx", "yyyy"];
  $scope.test = "";
});
```

*JS Fiddle:* http://jsfiddle.net/0ku4jvsn/5/

Nothing is bound with `$scope.test`. This line: `Exec type: {{test}}` is showing nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `$parent.test` when you bind your `ng-model` because you are in a `ng-repeat`

```
<label ng-repeat="x in list">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.test" value="{{ x }}" >{{x}} 
</label>
```

To selected a default value, just assign your model with your desired value

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) { 
    $scope.list = ["xxx", "yyyy"];
    $scope.test = $scope.list[0];
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0ku4jvsn/6/

Comment: how can I make "xxx" by default selected ?